# I want to run a dockerized script once every day on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a Dockerized Python Script that I want to run every day at a given time and email the results to `n` number of people. What would be the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Converting your python script logic to a Lambda function handler should be straight forward.And for the scheduling part you could set up a Cloud-watch event.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda supports deployments with containers. You would need to write a small amount of code to bridge the event driven programming model. After that I would use EventBridge schedule events (Used to be called CloudWatch events) to run the Lambda function on a schedule. You could then use Simple Email Service (SES) to send the emails.